# Hide and Show function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, toggle

How I can get the same functionality like http://pinsensor.com on the FAQ section. Like when you click the question the answer shows up and it hides when you click again.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist.

Comment: Google for jquery slideToggle()

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

Comment: try it here http://jsfiddle.net/subodhghulaxe/UXW4E/

Answer (score 1):

use `.toggle()` on click of your element

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/EwNRJ/901/

- http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
$('.yourclass').click(function(){
         $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: $("#content1").offset().top}, 2000);});
```

Answer (score 0):

They are using accordion plugin to make this kind of actions. There are lot of jquery accordion plugins available please use any thing to make this effect

They are using following plugin to make this action http://www.snyderplace.com/2011/02/jquery-accordion-plugin/